# How to get the last character of a string of a grok pattern

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

This is probably a dumb problem for most of you.

I'm pretty new with logstash grok.  I just successfully ran my grok pattern through grok debugger.

The following are values of severity_code from my grok pattern:

```
+LRGPSEVRI
+LRGPSEVRE
SQDC061I
```

I want to get the last character of each values, i.e. 'I' and 'E'. 
Since the value of the string varies in length, I cannot perform the logstash mutate, since all I've seen so far has to specify length.

Appreciate the help.
Thank you.

Comment: @baudsp, thanks for correcting the severity_code.  That's the way I entered in the question.  I didn't notice it was different when I submitted it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you can try

```
grok {
  match => ["severity_code", "(?<Severity>\B([EI])\b)"]
}
```

This is using regex and looks for an E or I in-front of a word barrier `\b`
and preceded by a non-word barrier `\B` (i.e. a letter).
If the severity is at the end of your string you should use the end anchor `$` instead: `(?<Severity>\B([EI])$)`

Comment: Thanks so much, wp78de.
This is very detail information.
I will apply this and test.
Thanks again.